# newer x64 slower than older x86 on iterating over an array?

Tags: c#, performance, x86, 64-bit

I iterate over a 3d array:

```
byte[, ,] data = original.Data;
for (int i = original.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     for (int j = original.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
     {
         if (data [i,j,0] < 100)
         {
            data [i, j, 0] += 100;
            data [i, j, 1] += 40;
            data [i, j, 2] += 243;
         }
         else
         {
            data [i,j,0] = 0;
         }
      }

    }
```

I tested this code with a quite old x86 CPU (Intel Core Duo) and a quite new x64 CPU (Intel i7). I was very surprised to see, that the newer x64 CPU was much slower. The x64 needed three times more time! What is wrong with that code? What can I do to make the x64 code faster?

Additional Info:
- Both tests were made on a win 7 os. (32-bit version for x86 and 64-bit version for x64)
- Code is C#

Comment: You can't really expect comparable results from two different OS's and two different chips, right? I bet the x86 machine has less RAM too. There's no way to compare these results.

Comment: I am observing similar behavior in a program when I run it on the same 64bit machine but compiling it either for x86 or for x64.  The x64 version runs half as fast.  I haven't verified if it is the whole code or just a small section.

Answer (score 2):

In general, many newer processors do tend to be slower than older processors, especially much older processors.

Newer processors, however, tend to have more cores and use much less power.  This is part of why multithreading is becoming so much more important - you can't rely on future hardware to provide speed benefits.

In addition, 64bit code often runs slower than similar 32bit code.  It does, however, provide other benefits, such as access to much larger amounts of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably get much faster results if you were operating on 32-bit or 64-bit values (even if you were operating on perhaps 4 byte values at a time).

Comment: How does Windows / .Net operate in x64 mode? Will it try to stuff two 32bit ints into a single 64bit line when loading from memory? If so it could be invalidating the caches if one gets changed and the other doesn't.

Comment: @Alex The VC++ compiler is definitely aware of alignment and will create structures that are aligned with performance in mind. So will the CLR.

Comment: I guess as long as they are arrays of value types, the clr will just smash them all together in the most efficient way possible. I think I will have to do some investigating to see how the clr does object offsets with x86/x86-64 and how it also does the same for value types, etc.   I have a reason to use SoS now!